# Roll on a D% Table for Special Materials

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, special-materials

The [magic weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons) and [magic armor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/) pages have a table that indicates whether the armor or weapon is made of a special material. But going to the [special materials page](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/), there's nothing to indicate how to pick the special material for the item you're creating.

I'm looking for a d% table that I could roll against to determine what material the weapon/armor I'm homebrewing could be made of. Does such a mechanism exist in Pathfinder 1e?

Comment: Regarding the Close Votes, I'd note that this *probably isn't* a shopping question; OP seems to be interested in if there is a table they are unaware of for determining [Treasure drops](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Placing%20Treasure&Category=Building%20an%20Adventure), not looking for a resource recommendations.

Comment: @Ifusaso is correct, I'm not looking for recommendations, I'm seeing if there are in-game mechanics to select what special materials are used for randomly-generated weapons and armor. I'm not looking for recommendations on how to select specific materials for weapons, I'm looking for the mechanic to do so. Could this question be opened up again, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are none. Since several sources provide different Special Materials (Abysium:PAP61, Adamantine:PZO1110 and so on), no single source seems to have a unifying table for us to roll. Not even the d20pfsrd.com or aonprd.com.

However, since there are only 46 *official* materials, I made the following table you could use. Please note that the table is **not official**, but a table I wrote in order to make it rollable with a d%.

When rolling treasure, for each piece of equipment that rolled a *Special Material*, roll on this table in the appropriate column. If the resulting material is not suitable for the equipment, simply roll again (i.e. Cold Iron Quarterstaff).

| Special Material | Weapon d% | Armor or Shield d% | Heavy Armor d% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abysium | 1-3 | 1-3 | 1-5 |
| Adamantine | 4-6 | 4-7 | 6-11 |
| Angelskin | - | 8-10 | - |
| Aszite | - | 11-12 | 12-15 |
| Blight Quartz | 7-9 | - | - |
| Bone | 10-12 | 13-16 | - |
| Bronze | 13-15 | 17-20 | - |
| Bulette Armor | - | 21-23 | 16-20 |
| Aquatic Armors | - | 24-26 | 21-25 |
| Cryptstone | 16-18 | - | - |
| Crystal, Blood | 19-21 | - | - |
| Darkleaf Cloth | - | 27-29 | - |
| Darkwood | 22-24 | 30-32 | - |
| Dragonhide | - | 33-36 | 26-30 |
| Dragonskin | 25-27 | - | - |
| Druchite | 28-29 | 37-38 | 31-34 |
| Eel Hide | - | 39-42 | - |
| Elysian Bronze | 30-32 | 43-46 | 35-40 |
| Gold | 33-34 | 47-48 | - |
| Greenwood | 35-37 | 49-51 | - |
| Griffon Mane | - | 52-54 | - |
| Horacalcum | 38-39 | 55-56 | 41-43 |
| Inubrix | 40-42 | - | - |
| Iron, Cold | 43-46 | - | - |
| Mindglass | 47-49 | 57-59 | 44-47 |
| Mithral | 50-52 | 60-63 | 48-51 |
| Noqual | 53-55 | 64-66 | 52-55 |
| Obsidian | 56-58 | - | - |
| Siccatite | 59-60 | 67-69 | 56-59 |
| Silver, Alchemical | 61-64 | - | - |
| Silversheen | 65-67 | - | - |
| Skymetal Alloys (glaucite) | 68-70 | 70-72 | 60-63 |
| Spiresteel | 71-72 | 73-74 | 64-66 |
| Steel, Fire-forged | 73-75 | 75-78 | 67-71 |
| Steel, Frost-Forged | 76-78 | 79-82 | 72-76 |
| Steel, Living | 79-81 | 83-86 | 77-81 |
| Steel, Singing | 82-84 | 87-90 | 82-86 |
| Stone | 85-87 | 91-93 | 87-91 |
| Sunsilver | 88-90 | 94-97 | 92-96 |
| Viridium | 91-92 | - | - |
| Voidglass | 93-95 | 98-00 | 97-00 |
| Whipwood | 96-98 | - | - |
| Wyroot | 99-00 | - | - |

I omitted some materials like *Basalt, Magic Bridge* and *Djezet* from the table, since they can't be used for weapons and armors.

I tried to keep the probabilities balanced, but some are more likely to be rolled than others.

Edit: On the occasions I got to use this table, it worked pretty well. I generated some pieces of equipment that I wouldn't have if I'd chosen the materials myself, but that were very interesting.
I did have to reroll for certain items (rolled darkleaf cloth for a shield once) but it usually works.
Sometimes when generating a themed treasure, or trying to keep it more consistent with the hoard's story, I rolled once and applied the material to several pieces of the same set.